# TestFlight error message

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using xCode 6 to develop applications. We have recently started using TestFlight in iTunes Connect. My questions is how to add multiple device to the TestFlight invitation. My iPhone 4S works well and accept the email from TestFlight. I also want to test it on a iPhone 5S, but I get an error message of "The requested app is not available or does not exist." Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Thanks in advance for any help - brand new to Apple dev and its idiosyncrasies.

Comment: I've received this message via TestFlight when our code-signing cert had expired.  You might want to check that.